# Windows 7 and UltraVNC

Tags: configuration, remote-desktop, settings, vnc

We are setting up an UltraVNC server on Windows 7. This box is to be controlled by a viewer from a device we have. The issue is that whenever we make a change, check something, change a password, check to use a new display driver, nothing sticks. We have tested this on Xp and all is fine. We are using the latest stable release and have the server loaded as a service. Has anyone run across this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The config file or registry key that the settings are stored in may be protected against changes with the new OS' permission model.

Try loading the VNC settings shortcut with 'Run as Administrator' option (right-click). The settings should now save.

Failing this try editing the configuration file and reg manually:
\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORL\WinVNC3\
%Program files%\UltraVNC

Comment: Mosty of these would have worked on any system, I was just far too lazy. We used another VNC client and things seemed to work appropriately.